# How to get module base url in yii2?

Tags: yii2

in Yii classic you would do something like this:

`Yii::app()->getModule('moduleName')->getBaseUrl();`

but I'm not sure how you get the base url in Yii2

Comment: yes sorry I meant base path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
\Yii::$app->getModule('moduleName')->basePath;
```